# How to solve ODataException in Postman while trying to use Sharepoint API to create an item in Sharepoint Online

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint, postman

Create list item using Sharepoint API v1

**Method**: POST

**Authorization**: Bearer Token

**API call**:

```
https://{{TenantName}}.sharepoint.com/sites/{{Sitename}}/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('{{ListName}} ')/items
```

**Headers**:

- Accept: application/json; odata=verbose
- Content-Type: application/json; odata=verbose
- Authorization: Bearer {{AccessToken}}

**Body (raw JSON)**:

```
{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.Data.Work_x0020_progress_x0020_trackerListItem"
  },
  "Title": "MyItem"
}
```

However i'm getting the below error message:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "Parsing JSON Light feeds or entries in requests without entity set is not supported. Pass in the entity set as a parameter to ODataMessageReader.CreateODataEntryReader or ODataMessageReader.CreateODataFeedReader method."
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

```
await this.context.spHttpClient
        .post(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}${request}`,
            SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
            {
                headers: [
                    ['Accept', 'application/json; odata=verbose'],
                    ['content-type', 'application/json; odata=verbose'],
                    ['X-RequestDigest', digest.FormDigestValue],
                    ['X-HTTP-Method', 'MERGE'],
                    ['If-Match', '*'],
                    ['odata-version', '']
                ],
                body: JSON.stringify(item)
            })
        .then((res: SPHttpClientResponse): void => {
            console.log("PostRequest");
            console.log(request);
            console.log(res);
            //debugger;
            return;
        });
```

just add this ['odata-version', ''], and it should works